# How to work with a Javascript +Date() numeric time stamp in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I've a JavaScript date string which I want to convert in understandable form. E.g.

```
new Date(1415988000000)
```

which gives the output

```
Fri Nov 14 2014 23:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I want to do this in python. I don't want to use PyV8. Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: I'm just curious... why do you have to use JavaScript in Python? Are you writing some tool to analyze js code or what?

Comment: Since you're in a Python environment, what's wrong with using `from datetime import date` then `foo = date(1415988000000)` and for _String_ representation use e.g. `foo.ctime()`

Comment: I'm getting this information (date) from the response (JSON format) of an api call which I need to convert in actual date format before storing in the database.

Comment: Sorry I meant `foo = date.fromtimestamp(1415988000000 // 1000)` (integer division)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write Javascript in Python to convert the timestamps.

The following works in pure python.

Note:

- The JS Date format is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1,1970 UTC.
- Oddly enough, the python format for time.time() is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC.

This standard is sometimes called [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

First, for the milliseconds to seconds time conversion, you need to divide 1415988000000 by 1000, obtaining 1415988000

Then you can use the `datetime` library like this:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1415988000)
print d
```

Obtaining:

2014-11-14 13:00:00

This print seems to have converted `d` to my TZ which is UTC-5.

So UTC time would be 18:00.

This explains the later time, 23:30, you receive in JS for the same stamp in IST or UTC+5:30

Comment: Thank You ! Got it now. I didn't knew about the standard unix time that it is in seconds instead of milliseconds, so I was getting year out of range ValueError.

Comment: Yeah that will do it.  Good luck.